# Function in racket that swaps two symbols in a list of symbols

Tags: racket

I'm trying to write a function using higher order functions in racket that consumes two symbols, sym1 and sym2, and a list of symbols, and returns the list with every instance of sym1 and sym2 swapped.

I figured out how to do this with an accumulator function, but I'm just curious how this would work with higher order functions, because they require one parameter functions, rather than a single variable. Thanks!

```
  (define (swapper/ho str1 str2 los)
  (local
    [(define (swapper-acc los acc)
       (cond
         [(empty? los) acc]
         [(symbol=? str1 (first los))
          (swapper-acc (rest los) (append acc (list str2)))]
         [(symbol=? str2 (first los))
          (swapper-acc (rest los) (append acc (list str1)))]
         [else
          (swapper-acc (rest los) (append acc (list (first los))))]))]
    (swapper-acc los empty)))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a solution with higher-order functions, look no further - [`foldr`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/pairs.html#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Flist..rkt%29._foldr%29%29) will do the trick:

```
(define (swapper/ho str1 str2 los)
  (foldr (lambda (e acc)
           (cond ((symbol=? e str1) (cons str2 acc))
                 ((symbol=? e str2) (cons str1 acc))
                 (else (cons e acc))))
         '()
         los))
```

Also, your solution can be improved - it's a bad idea to use `append` when building an output list (it's very inefficient), use `cons` instead. In fact, this is exactly the kind of problem that you'd solve using the usual template for recursively traversing a list, you don't even need a local helper or an accumulator:

```
(define (swapper/ho str1 str2 los)
  (cond ((empty? los)
         empty)
        ((symbol=? str1 (first los))
         (cons str2 (swapper/ho str1 str2 (rest los))))
        ((symbol=? str2 (first los))
         (cons str1 (swapper/ho str1 str2 (rest los))))
        (else
         (cons (first los) (swapper/ho str1 str2 (rest los))))))
```

For example:

```
(swapper/ho 'x 'y '(a x b c y d x y))
=> '(a y b c x d y x)
```

Comment: It did! Thank you so much!